# How can I count the messages coming from a view inside a template?

Tags: django, django-messages

I'm using Django's [messages framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/messages/) to pass messages from my view functions to my templates. I want a template to contain some HTML only if the number of messages is greater than 1. Is there a way to do this?

I've tried the following:

```
{% if messages.count > 1 %}

    <html for multiple messages>

{% else %}

    <html for just one message>

{% endif %}
```

But `messages.count` doesn't seem to exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`messages` has a `__len__` function, so it can be used with the `length` template filter:

```
{% if messages|length > 1 %}

    <html for multiple messages>

{% else %}

    <html for just one message>

{% endif %}
```

See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/templates/builtins/#length